# no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void>’

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile this [repo](https://github.com/florianbenz/bil/tree/master/src) in Linux, but I have some trouble in this step.

*util/BinarySerialization.hpp

```
template <typename T> inline
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void>::type
writeBinary(const T& data, std::ostream& outputStream)
{
    ...
}

template <typename T> inline
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void>::type
writeBinary(const std::vector<T>& data, std::ostream& outputStream)
{
    ...
}

template <typename T> inline
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void>::type
writeBinary(const std::vector<T>& data, std::ostream& outputStream)
{
    // write vector length
    size_t length = data.size();
    outputStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&length), sizeof(length));
    if (!outputStream) throw IOException();
    // write vector data one by one
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        writeBinary(data[i], outputStream); // error!
}

void writeBinary(const std::string& data, std::ostream& outputStream);
```

*serialization/ElementBS.cpp

```
void bil::writeBinary(const Element& data, std::ostream& outputStream)
{
    writeBinary(data.m_name, outputStream);
    writeBinary(data.m_options, outputStream);
}
```

*xdlrc/model/Element.hpp

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> ConfigurationOptions;

class Element {
public:
    Element();

    std::string& name();
    const std::string& name() const;
    ConfigurationOptions& options();
    const ConfigurationOptions& options() const;
    void clear();

private:
    friend void writeBinary(const Element& data, std::ostream& outputStream);
    friend void readBinary(Element& data, std::istream& inputStream);

    std::string m_name;
    ConfigurationOptions m_options;

};
```

> util/BinarySerialization.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void >::type bil::writeBinary(const std::vector<T>&, std::ostream&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_pod<T>, void>::type = void; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]':
>   serialization/ElementBS.cpp:16:45:   required from here
>   util/BinarySerialization.hpp:78:21: error: no matching function for call to 'writeBinary(const value_type&, std::ostream&)'
>             writeBinary(data[i], outputStream);
>   ...
>   BinarySerialization.hpp:31:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::enable_if<boost::is_pod<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, void>'

The first writeBinary in ElementBS.cpp match with the last function in BinarySerialization.hpp, and the 2nd function in ElementBS.cpp match with the 3rd function. But, writeBinary(data[i], outputStream); in 3rd function couldn't match any functions. I don't know how to fix it;

Comment: `void writeBinary(const std::string& data, std::ostream& outputStream);` i only see decleration in here. where is the funcion definition?

Comment: The function definition is in util/BinarySerialization.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the compiler error make sure declaration `void writeBinary(const std::string& data, std::ostream& outputStream);` precedes `writeBinary` function templates.

This is because during template instantiation, the second phase of dependent name lookup only argument-dependent name look up is performed. Since arguments to `writeBinary(const std::string& data, std::ostream& outputStream)` come from namespace `std` the argument-dependent name lookup never finds this overload because it is not in namespace `std`.

By declaring that function prior to function templates that use it you make that function available during the first phase of the two-phase lookup. This name is then considered during function template instantiation, the second phase of name lookup.